# Errors in a promise's error handler go missing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, promise

If I throw an error in a promise's `catch` handler, the error is never bubbled up!

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(function() { return foo.bar(); })
  .then(function() { return console.log('ok!'); })
  .catch(function(err) { return baz.quux(); });
```

In both Node v0.8 with the [promise](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/promisejs.org) module and Chrome 36's JavaScript console, this prints nothing. I'm expecting to see `ReferenceError: baz is not defined` appear *somewhere*.

Shouldn't we see *something*? Is this a part of the promises spec that I missed?

**UPDATE**: Clarification: this happens in Chrome 36's V8 without any third-party module.

Comment: Add another `.catch(console.error.bind(console))` and it should show up. Apparently the `promise` module doesn't have logging of unhandled rejections. Or use `.done()` which throws exceptions from the handlers, instead of rejecting the promise.

Comment: Clarification: This happens in Chrome 36's V8 without any third-party module.

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, both `foo.bar()` and `baz.quux()` should throw exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a problem promise implementations face. However the two you've chosen fail at it pretty bad. Indeed - the error is swallowed in your case and indeed you will not get any indication of this silent failure unless you attach a error handler yourself.

Your options are:

- Use a library that offers `.done` like Q and manually append `.done` to every single promise in your code to indicate you will not attach handlers to it.
- Use a library like Bluebird or When that does unhandled rejection detection.

In particular, Bluebird is faster than native promises and does this properly. It is also a superset of native promises so you can write code that uses that subset if you'd like (although it has a much richer API). The code you have above logs an unhandled rejection with Bluebird.

By the way, Firefox handles this much better and Firefox native promises detect unhandled rejections.